# How to add to returnUr custom params. I use context express checkout method(paypal)

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I tried to set parameters on the returnUrl.
example returnUrl www.mysite.com/orderPage/?videoId=entryname&videoName=item.
but its return error. Is there away to add returnUrl custom params.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the "PAYMENTREQUEST_n_CUSTOM" parameter? you can use it to place any data of your own use. Add this paremeter to your SetExpressCheckout call and later get it back with your GetExpressCheckout call.

[Documentation for SetExpressCheckout  api call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/SetExpressCheckout_API_Operation_NVP/)

[Documentation for GetExpressCheckout api call](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/GetExpressCheckoutDetails_API_Operation_NVP/)

Comment: Optionally, you can just place all in session variables as all this process occurs in the same user session.